# How to improve my Apex skills

Tags: apex

I would like to improve my Apex skills, especially in Test Classes. Could someone tell some trails and modules to someone who is a beginner?

Comment: Definitely look at this: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro

Comment: see also [canonical-qa](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-qa) here on stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce Trailhead is the best place to learn Apex test classes.  Also, you can refer to sample test class examples that already has a test class and try to understand and decode the logic written.

Below are a few Test Class Best Practices.

- Use @isTest at the Top for all the test classes.
- Always put assert statements for negative and positive tests.
- Use the @testSetup method to insert the test data into the test class that will flow all over the test class.
- Always use Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() doing this it will increase the
  governor limit of salesforce.
- Use System.runAs() method to test the functionality in user Context.
- Do not put (seeAllData = true) in test class otherwise, use it for exceptional cases.
- Avoid Using Hard Coding Ids anywhere in test Class or any apex class.
- Make sure that each class has a minimum of 75% coverage and also the functionality has been covered.

Test Class References:

[Understanding Testing in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_intro.htm)

[Apex Testing Module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing)